# Basis for topology on half open sets in R

Tags: general-topology

Hi I was trying to determine the basis of the topology on the following collection in R {[a,b), a <b}.

Here is what I tried : Knowing that the basis for a subspace topology is equal to the set of all intersections of {[a,b), a <b} with the basis of the topology it is a subspace to.
Now I also know that the basis for the euclidean topology on R is {(a,b), a <b}. Can I just take the intersection of {[a,b), a <b} and {(a,b), a <b} to get the basis? If so what does this equal? Or am I totally wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The collection $\{[a,b)\ |\ a<b\}$ is not a topology. But it already is a basis for some topology (more precisely: the topology generated by it). Also why you mention subspace topology and the euclidean topology? You don't have subspaces here, and the euclidean topology seems irrelevant.

Comment: My apologies you are ofc right. I misphrased my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, we consider the subspace $C = [a, b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, where $a < b$. You can show that if $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology on $X$, and $A$ is a subspace of $X$, then the collection $\{ A \cap B | B \in \mathcal{B} \}$ is a basis for the topology on $A$. Thus, a basis for $C$ is the collection $\{ C \cap (x, y) | x, y \in \mathbb{R} \}$. You can verify that each element in this basis has one of two forms. The first is $[a, r)$, where $r \in C$. The other is $(l, r)$, where $l, r \in C$.

Comment: thx! sorry if my question wasn't that clear but you really helped me out :) !